# Relation in Protege with three Entities

Tags: protege, rdfs

I have a ontology for movies with this classes
Actor - Producer - Movie

and I need to do this relation:
Producer pay to Actor for a Movie

I already do some work but I dont know if i am in the correct way...
this is what i did:

I create Bill Class
and I create this three object properties:

- paid by (the domain is bill and range is producer)
- on movie (the domain is bill and range is movie)
- to actor ( the domain is bill and range is actor)

and also i create this data property:

- amount (for the bill money) with range integer

How I can do it?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/